# Extension of scalars of an irreducible representation - Is it a direct sum over a single orbit of Galois conjugates?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, galois-theory

Let $L/F$ be a field extension which is Galois, $\text{char}F=0$. Let $V$ be an irreducible representation of a finite group $G$ over $F$. Then, the representation $W=L\otimes V$ of $G$ over $L$ is Galois-invariant. That is $W^{\sigma}$ is isomorphic to $W$ for each $\sigma\in\text{Gal}(L/F)$.

The Galois invariance implies that the representation $W$ decomposes as $\bigoplus_{i=1}^{n}W_i$ where each $W_i$ is the direct sum of an entire $\text{Gal}(L/K)$-orbit of irreps of $G$ over $L$.

Is $n=1$ always? That is, is there always just a single orbit in the decomposition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my previous answer was wrong. I can't delete it, because it is an accepted answer, but I can edit it and completely change its contents!

I was confusing isomorphism classes of submodules with the submodules themselves.

According to Theorem 13.3, Chapter 5 of Huppert's German book "Endliche Gruppen I", in your situation. we have $W =\oplus_{i=1}^k U^{\sigma_i}$, where $U$ is an irreducible $LG$-submdule of $W$, and $\{\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_k\}$ is a (possibly proper) subset of ${\rm Gal}(L,F)$. (I haven't found a reference for this in English yet.)

I guess the answer to your question depends on what exactly you mean by "each $W_i$  is the direct sum of an entire ${\rm Gal}(L/K)$-orbit of irreps of $G$ over $L$".

Comment: Thanks. In your example we got two copies of the same orbit. Do we always get several copies of the same orbit?

Comment: I think so, because the isomorphism classes of the constituents of $L \otimes V$ form a single orbit of the action of the Galois group on the set of isomorphism classes of irreducible $L$-representations.

Comment: Sounds good, but why is that?

Comment: I meant that $W_i$ is formed as follows: Take an irreducible representation $U$ over $L$, consider a set $X$ consisting of Galois conjugates of $U$ and such that every Galois conjugate of $U$ is isomorphic to exactly one representation in $X$. Now, let $W_i$ be the direct sum of the representations in $X$. Your original answer shows that it sometime $n > 1$. However, it seems that $V$ is a direct sum of several copies of the same $W_i$, constructed as above.

Comment: By the way, the downside of editing an answer rather than writing a new one is that I did not get a notification for the edit. Oh, and sorry for writing "representation $U$" again. In my mind, when I think "representation" I think "L[G]-module", and it's hard to get rid of this habit.

Comment: As I said before, my original answer was wrong, which was why I edited it out. The theorem in Huppert's book says that the answer to your question is yes, we always have $n=1$.

Comment: Just to make sure: In your direct sum which defines $W$, some summands can be isomorphic, right?

Comment: Yes that's right. In the example I gave in my original answer, the two summands were isomorphic. But in that example there is an element of the Galois group that maps one to the other.